# How to fix .vscode tracking in gitignore

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble using `.gitignore` with my `.vscode` folder in my repository.

I added a rule in my `.gitignore` to ignore my entire `.vscode/` folder:

```
# Visual Studio Code # 
.vscode/* 
.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/settings.json 
!.vscode/tasks.json 
!.vscode/launch.json 
!.vscode/extensions.json 
.history.vscode/settings.json
```

Despite this, `.vscode` is still being tracked by my local git repository. I've tried a variety of different solutions including using `git filter-branch` to remove this folder from my git history and `git rm --cached .vscode` to clear my cache and re-commit my changes, but none of these solutions prevents the .vscode folder from being tracked by git.

When I run `git status` I keep getting this result:

```sh
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .vscode/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So far, I've worked around this by manually excluding this folder when I `git add` my changes.

Why is `.vscode/` still being shown as untracked? If I were to `git add .` and `git commit` this, it would add this folder to my git history and eventually to my remote repository when I `git push`. I don't want this behavior to occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Your .gitignore file seems contradictory. You have ".vscode/settings.json", which means ignore that file, and then the next line you have the same thing preceded with an exclamation mark, which includes it again.

Comment: @m0j0 yes, I did this to explicitly try to ignore my settings.json file within .vscode when I was looking for different solutions

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Maybe try this in your .gitignore. This should ignore the entire .vscode directory, no matter where it is located.

```
**/.vscode/
```

Comment: This is the solution and working like a charm. This should be the most upvoted answer...

Answer (score 52):

Had similar problem, turned out the files were added to my cache. Clearing it with below command worked.

```
git rm --cached .vscode/settings.json
```

Reference to the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40742) on github where I found the solution.

Comment: "fatal: pathspec '.vscode/settings.json' did not match any files" :)))

Comment: obviously. the root folder

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and nothing from the mentioned here helped me. Finally I found the reason:

> Essentially, a .gitignore list does not work to ignore files that are
> already committed into the Git repository.
> This means that if you:
>
> 1. Make a commit to your Git repository, and then;
> 2. Set up your .gitignore list.
>
> Then the .gitignore list will NOT ignore files that are already tracked by
> your repository. Hence, to avoid this, you’ll want to ensure .gitignore is
> set up before you make any commits.

The source is [here](https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/06/how-to-fix-gitignore-not-working-on-your-repository/)

Answer (score 2):

Happened for an Untracked git file `.vscode/settings.json`. Turned out to be a second line in our huge `.gitignore` file that was overriding the effort. In example below simply remove the bottom line.

Remember to re-stage and commit `.gitgnore` after the change.

```
# IDEs and editors
.settings/
.vscode/settings.json   -- Line I added that "was not working"
...

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json  -- Line discovered that was overriding above (REMOVE)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As there can be three types of files(tracked, untracked, and ignored). The files which are already tracked or indexed can't be ignored just by adding them to the .gitignore. Rather their index should be deleted. Then if you add them in the .gitignore  it will be ignored.

Suppose you have a tracked file in the **root** named **test.txt** now you are adding this file to the .gitignore. It will not work unless you remove it from the git index like below

```
 git rm --cached test.txt
```

Also, you can use the relative path of a file to remove it if they are not in the root.

Then the index will be deleted and git will stage them as files deleted but they won't be deleted from your local.

Comment: This was my problem! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you committed a file inside the `.vscode` directory before, and now you are adding `.vscode` into your `.gitignore` file, it is not going to ignore the whole directory, because there is a commit associated with one of the files in this directory.

However, any new files inside that directory will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me as the offending folder (a Nanoc site with an "output" folder) was outside the git repository (work that one out!), so I removed the folder from the directory with the git-tracked files, created an empty new one with the same name in the same location, checked that it was no longer tracked by VSCode. then dragged all the files back into the newly-ignored folder from the original "output" folder.